# Redux action is redirecting in React Native

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I have a React Native app that uses redux.
The app also uses drawer navigator (react-navigation).
There a redux action that updates user profile.

The problem is that when i call a the redux action to update user profile, it is redirecting to previous screen. However, i'm not calling any redirect commands.

Here is my code that updates profile with redux action:

```
userService
  .updateProfile(form)
  .then((resp) => {
    // after updateProfile action, its being redirected
    this.props.updateProfile(resp.profile);
  })
  .catch((err) => this.props.showError(err, "server"))
  .finally(() => this.setState({ loading: false }));
```

Anyone can help me to find what is the problem?